# All nodes reachable from source in residual network of any max flow are included in $S$ for any min-cut $(S,T)$

Tags: graphs, network-flow, minimum-cuts

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed graph with source $s$ and sink $t$ and $s \neq t$.
For each edge $e \in E$, we have $c(e) \in \Bbb N$.

Also, we are given a max flow function $f$ on that network.

Let $R_f$ be the residual network of $f$.

I would like to prove that the set formed by all the nodes reachable from $s$ in $R_f$ is a subset of $S$ from any min-cut $(S,T)$.

I tried to write a proof by contradiction but I'm just getting stuck every time trying to analyze the Min-Cut after removing a certain node.

Comment: Hint, for a path starting at $s$ to reach a node in $T$, it must cross the cut.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to understand [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Main_theorem) and [its proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem#Proof). The following observation is a corollary of that theorem basically.

**Lemma**. Let $f$ be a max-flow and $\mathcal C=(S, T)$ be a min-$(s,t)$-cut. Then

- for any edge $(u,v)$ such that $u\in S$ and $v\in T$, $f((u,v))=c((u,v))$.
- for any edge $(u,v)$ such that $u\in T$ and $v\in S$, $f((u,v))=0$.

In plain words, the lemma says that $f$ must use all capacities of all edges crossing $\mathcal C$ without using any capacities of any edge going the other way.

**Proof**. The conservation of flows implies that $|f|=f_{out}(S)-f_{in}(S)$. Since $f_{out}(S)\le c(\mathcal C)=|f|$, where $c(\mathcal C)$ is the capacity of $\mathcal C$ and $f_{in}(S) \ge0$, we must have $f_{out}(S)= c(\mathcal C)$ and $f_{in}(S)=0$. $\checkmark$

---

The lemma above means that given any min-cut $(S, T)$, in the residual network $R_f$, no edge of positive capacity goes from $S$ to $T$ since

- the capacity of any edge that goes from $S$ to $T$ is reduced to $0$ in $R_f$, and
- the "pushed-back capacity" of any edge that goes from $T$ to $S$ is $0$ since $f$ is 0 on those edges.

In other words, any path of edges of positive capacity in $R_f$ cannot cross the cut $(S,T)$. So, any path of edges of positive capacity that starts from $s$, which is a node in $S$, must stay in $S$. $\checkmark$

---

**Exercise (every maximal flow yields the same minimal cut)**
Given a flow network $(G,s,t,c)$ and a flow $f$, let $S_f$ be the set of all vertices that are reachable from $s$ in the residual network of $f$. Given two maximal flows $f_1$ and $f_2$, show that $S_{f_1}=S_{f_2}$.

Comment: thank you for the answer and the edit!
the proof approach is much more clear to me now.

Comment: You are welcome.